# How to Insert HTML Tags in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to insert **Meta Tag**. But when I view the html in browser, the meta tags are not shown.

code:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
static void metaTags() {
    html.Element? head = html.document.querySelector('head');
    head?.appendHtml('<meta name="description" content="Here is meta tag!">');
  }
```

I am getting `Removing disallowed element <META> from [object DocumentFragment]` this error in Debug Console

Thanks

Comment: You have to wait late enough... I'm about to do a screencast on where I set the title and meta data for any page generated.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Ya i have wait enough. I am also getting ```Removing disallowed element <TITLE> from [object DocumentFragment]``` in my debug console

Answer (score 0):

There is an [HtmlElementViewer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/HtmlElementView-class.html) that will help you out with this. You give it a `BodyElement` with the `dart:html` library.

There are also packages like [these](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_web_view) that will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try NodeValidatorBuilder from dart:html

```
  head?.appendHtml('<meta name="description" content="Here is meta tag!">');
    validator: html.NodeValidatorBuilder()
..allowHtml5(uriPolicy: ItemUrlPolicy())
```